# Find (with a proof ) lim$_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^n \frac{(1 -\frac{x}{n})^n}{ne^{-x}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, functions

So I am pretty sure I want to start off with defining $f_n = \frac{(1 -\frac{x}{n})^n}{ne^{-x}}$ if $x >0$, and then use something like the bounded convergence theorem or dominated convergence theorem.

---

Comment: Is there a reason to write $e^{-x}$ in the denominator rather than just having $e^x$ in the numerator?

Comment: Did you try simple things like substitution $t \gets \frac xn$ and/or partial integration?

Comment: So this integral is equal to lim$_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^n e^{t/n}(1 -t)^n dt$ and then using integration by parts we get lim$_{n \rightarrow \infty} ne^{t/n}(1-t)^n + n^2\int_0^n e^{t/n}(1-t)^n$

Answer (score 2):

Use the substitution $u = 1 - \frac{x}{n}$ to get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\left(ue^{1-u}\right)^n\:du$$

Now the key to this problem is taking a look at the integrand on the interval $(0,1)$

$$\frac{d}{du}(ue^{1-u}) = (1-u)e^{1-u} = 0 \implies u = 1$$

And since the integrand vanishes at $u=0$, this means $u=1$ is a max and the function is less than $1$ on $(0,1)$, meaning

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\left(ue^{1-u}\right)^n\:du \to \int_0^1 0\:du = 0$$

by dominated convergence. Now had the original integral not had the $n$ in the denominator, we would have gotten something more interesting, namely

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^n\frac{\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n}{e^{-x}}\:dx = 1$$

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow. I know what an asymptote is but I don't know that it means to have a relationship asymptotically

Comment: @SamanthaWyler sequences approach limits, but it is an equally valid question to ask, how fast do they do that? The definition of the big-O notation is as follows. If there exists a $C>0$ such that $$|a_n-L| \leq Cf(n)$$  (where $L$ is the limit of the sequence), then we can say that $$a_n = L + O(f(n))$$

Comment: Essentially what the asymptotic relationship in the answer means is that for large enough $n$ $$\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n \approx e^{-x} + \frac{C}{n}$$ is really good approximation to the actual value. In this case $C = -\frac{e^{-x}x^2}{2}$

Comment: @NinadMunshi By your last comment, you actually get $$
 \approx \int_0^n {\frac{1}{n}dx}  - \int_0^n {\frac{{x^2 }}{{2n^2 }}dx}  = 1 - \frac{n}{6}.
$$ In your answer you forgot to take into account that the big-$O$ depends on $x$.

Comment: @Gary that is a very good point! Then the answer is more complicated since I can't just assert it diverges when there's a complicated alternating series.

Answer (score 2):

By a simple change of variables, we have
$$
I_n := \int_0^n {\frac{{\left( {1 - \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n }}{{ne^{ - x} }}dx}  = \int_0^1 {\left[ {(1 - t)e^t } \right]^n dt} .
$$
Now,
$$
0 \le (1 - t)e^t  = 1 - \frac{{t^2 }}{2}e^\xi  (1 + \xi ) \le 1 - \frac{{t^2 }}{2} \le e^{ - t^2 /2} 
$$
with a suitable $\xi \in (0,1)$ (Taylor's formula with Lagrange remainder). Hence,
$$
0 \le I_n  \le \int_0^1 {e^{ - nt^2 /2} dt} .
$$
By the dominated convergence theorem, the right-hand side tends to $0$ and thus $I_n \to 0$. If you do not want to use dominated convergence, note that
$$
I_n  \le \int_0^1 {e^{ - nt^2 /2} dt}  \le \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - nt^2 /2} dt}  = \sqrt {\frac{\pi }{{2n}}} .
$$

Answer (score 1):

You could obtain much more than the limit. Considering $$I_n=\int_0^n\frac{ \left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^n}{n}\,e^x\,dx$$ let $x=nt$ to make
$$I_n=\int_0^1 (1-t)^n \,e^{n t}\,dt$$
$$J_n=\int (1-t)^n \,e^{n t}\,dt=e^n \, n^{-(n+1)}\,\Gamma (n+1,n(1-t))$$
$$I_n=e^n \, n^{-(n+1)}\,\Big[\Gamma (n+1) -\Gamma (n+1,n) \Big]$$
$$I_n=e^n \, n^{-(n+1)}\,\Gamma (n+1)\Big[1 -\frac{\Gamma (n+1,n)}{\Gamma (n+1)}  \Big]$$ When $n$ is very large
$$\Big[1 -\frac{\Gamma (n+1,n)}{\Gamma (n+1)}  \Big]\to \frac 12$$ For the remaining, use logarithms and Stirling approximation, to get
$$\log\Big[e^n \, n^{-(n+1)}\,\Gamma (n+1)\Big]=\frac{1}{2} \log \left(\frac{2 \pi }{n}\right)+\frac{1}{12 n}-\frac{1}{360n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$
$$I_n= \sqrt{\frac{ \pi}{2n}} \exp \left(\frac{1}{12 n}-\frac{1}{360n^3}+\cdots \right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Trying for $n=10^6$, the exact value is $0.00125265$ while the approximation gives $0.00125331$.